# Do homomorphisms preserve subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $(A, \cdot), (B, \ast)$ be groups, and $\phi: A \mapsto B$ a homomorphism. Then:
   $$ S \leq A \Rightarrow \phi(S) \leq B $$

I think this must be a false statement, because there is no guarantee that $\textrm{Ker}(\phi) \subset S$. Yet, I have written the following proof for this statement:

\begin{align*}
    &\quad\; S \leq A \\
&\{\text{definition of subgroup}\} \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \forall s, t \in S \mid s \cdot t \in S \;\wedge\; s^{-1} \in S \\
&\{\text{definition of set inclusion}\} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall s, t \in S \mid (\exists u \in S \mid s \cdot t = u) \;\wedge\; (\exists v \in S \mid v = s^{-1}) \\
&\{\text{(problematic step?) $\phi$ is well-defined, so $x = y \Rightarrow \phi(x) = \phi(y)$}\} \\
&\Rightarrow \forall \phi(s), \phi(t) \in \phi(S) \mid (\exists \phi(u) \in \phi(S) \mid \phi(s \cdot t) = \phi(u)) \;\wedge\; (\exists \phi(v) \in \phi(S) \mid \phi(v) = \phi(s^{-1})) \\
&\{\text{definition of set inclusion}\} \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \forall \phi(s), \phi(t) \in \phi(S) \mid\phi(s \cdot t) \in \phi(S) \;\wedge\; \phi(s^{-1}) \in \phi(S)  \\
&\{\text{$\phi$ is a homomorphism, thus preserves the product, and inverse}\}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow \forall \phi(s), \phi(t) \in \phi(S) \mid\phi(s) \ast \phi(t) \in \phi(S) \;\wedge\; {\phi(s)}^{-1} \in \phi(S) \\
&\{\text{definition of subgroup}\} \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \phi(S) \leq B
   \end{align*}

I think the (weakest) correct statement should be:

$$ \textrm{Ker}(\phi) \subset S \;\wedge\; S \leq A \Rightarrow \phi(S) \leq B $$

Is this the case? If yes, how can I correct my proof to capture this issue? If not, why not?

Comment: But it is not a false statement.

Comment: Your condition in the end will guarantee something strictly better, namely that $S = \phi^{-1}(\phi(S))$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So I must be misunderstanding something! Shouldn't we also need the guarantee that $\textrm{Ker}(\phi) \subset S$? There might be subgroups of $A$ which do not contain $\textrm{Ker}{\phi}$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have edited my question to better clarify my new position: I am uncertain whether it is a false statement or not.

Comment: Why do you think that $\phi(S)$ being a subgroup of $B$ hinges on whether $\mbox{Ker}(\phi)\subset S$? Suppose that $\phi(s)=1$ for all $s\in S$. Then $\phi(S)=\{1\}$ is definitely a subgroup of $B$.

Comment: @Scounged Hmm. Okay, maybe that condition was too strong --- still, $S$ has to contain some element of $\textrm(Ker)(\phi)$? Say that no element of $\textrm{Ker}(\phi)$ is in $S$. Then $\phi(S)$ cannot be a subgroup in $B$, because it cannot contain $\textrm{id}_{B}$?

Comment: @user89 Note that homomorphisms always map the identity to the identity due to the property $\phi(st)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$, so the kernel of $\phi$ is never empty. And since $S$ is a subgroup it will definitely contain the identity element.

Comment: @Scounged of course! *facepalm*!